# Insert values into an associative array within a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am new working with php, I am using a foreach loop to traverse an array of decoded objects. I would like to enter values to a new array for each iteration. This is a part of the code:

```
//example of array before decoding it [{"id":1,"quantity":12, other values...},{"id":2,"quantity":13,other values...}]
$data = json_decode($request->data); 
$newArray = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value){
  $newArray[$key] = $value->{'id'} //[1,2,3....]
}
```

at the moment I am generating a one-dimensional array, what I need is to obtain an array of this type:

```
[
    1 => ['quantity' => $other], 
    2 => ['quantity' => $other]
]
```

where 'other' would be another value that I get from my loop `$value->{'other'}`. How can I generate this?

Comment: Would you like to give us a look at an least an example of the array you are processing

Comment: @RiggsFolly edit my question adding the example.

Comment: no, the key that I want to assign to everything is '' quantity "

Comment: Interesting question

Answer (score 7):

I'm not 100% confident, whether I really got your question ... but this is probably what you want:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$value->id] = ['quantity' => $value->quantity];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

after `json_decode` you have objects of type `stdClass`, so you can access the properties like shown above.

Comment: ....although why bother deserialilizing the JSON into a stdobject when you are treating as an array (you can deserialize to an array directly)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why you need `quantity` keys in one element arrays. Without this you can simply use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) function:

```
$items = json_decode($json);
// $items = json_decode($json, true); // For PHP < 7.0

$result = array_column($items, 'quantity', 'id');
```

But if you sure that `quantity` keys are necessary you can map the result using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php):

```
$result = array_map(function ($quantity) {
   return ['quantity' => $quantity]; 
}, $result);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aed2a0e38217d6d50381fc4812681d32174c3c60).

Answer (score 2):

Using a loop, you would do something like this:

```
$data = '[{"id":1,"quantity":12},{"id":2,"quantity":13}]';
$decoded = json_decode($data, $as_array = true); // decode as array, not object
$accumulator = [];
foreach($decoded as $index=>$values) {
    $accumulator[$values['id']] = ['quantity' => $values['quantity']];
}
print_r($accumulator);
```

The same concept can be expressed more clearly in a functional manner with [`array_reduce`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$data = '[{"id":1,"quantity":12},{"id":2,"quantity":13}]';
$decoded = json_decode($data, $as_array = true); // decode as array, not object
$reduced = array_reduce($decoded, function($carry, $entry){
    $carry[$entry['id']] = ['quantity' => $entry['quantity']];
    return $carry;
}, $initial_value = []);
print_r($reduced);
```

Both approaches would generate the same output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 13
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you are expecting like this,

```
$request = new stdClass();
$request->data = '[{"id":1,"quantity":12,"name":"item 1","code":"ITM-111"},{"id":2,"quantity":13,"name":"item 2","code":"ITM-222"}]';

$data = json_decode($request->data);
$newArray = array();

print_r($data);
```

*example:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [quantity] => 12
            [name] => item 1
            [code] => ITM-111
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [quantity] => 13
            [name] => item 2
            [code] => ITM-222
        )

)

$other = 'name'; // required key

foreach($data as $value){
    $newArray[$value->id] = [ 
        'quantity' => $value->quantity,
        'name' => $value->{$other}
    ];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

*output :*

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 12
            [name] => item 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 13
            [name] => item 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple foreach loop

```
$json='[{"id":1,"quantity":12, "ov":1,"ov2":2},{"id":2,"quantity":13,"ov":"other values"}]';
echo "<pre/>";
$a=json_decode($json,TRUE);
foreach($a as $val){
    $arr=$val;
    unset($arr['id']);
    $new_arr[$val['id']]=$arr;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Your question is not clear, if you are trying to put quantity on key , try something like below

```
$json='[{"id":1,"quantity":12, "ov":1,"ov2":2},{"id":2,"quantity":13,"ov":"other values"}]';
echo "<pre/>";
$a=json_decode($json,TRUE);
foreach($a as $val){
    $arr=$val;
    unset($arr['id']);
    $temp=$arr;
    unset($temp['quantity']);
    $new_arr[$val['id']]=[$arr['quantity']=>$temp];
}
print_r($new_arr);


Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [ov] => 1
                    [ov2] => 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [13] => Array
                (
                    [ov] => other values
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to generate the array as you described. I've added example values for the `other` property to help illustrate.

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    $request_data = '[{"id":1,"quantity":12,"other":"Other 1"},{"id":2,"quantity":13,"other":"Other 2"}]';

    $data = json_decode($request_data);
    $newArray = array();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $newArray[$value->id] = array(
            'quantity' => $value->other
        );
    }

    print_r($newArray);

    // Returns:

    /*
    Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => Other 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => Other 2
            )

    )
    */
```

Answer (score -3):

You could append array using something like this:

```
foreach($file_data as $value) {
    list($value1, $value2, $value3) = explode('|', $value);
    $item = array(
        'value1' => $value1, 
        'value2' => $value2, 
        'value3' => $value3
    );
    $file_data_array[] = $item;
}
```

For more informations, take a look at the following:
[Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Comment: Please dont invent answer that have nothing to do with the question